# How to draw image at angle in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing

I want to draw a image at angle. I have one `ImageView` with contect mode `Aspect to fit`. Also I have one `dragView` which user can move and rotate on the View. I have moved the dragView with `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`

Both the `ImageView` and `dragView` is added on the main (self) view.

I have done the following code.

It has two problem

1. I dont know how to save image at angle that i can get from the `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`
2. dragView is not placed currently on the image. it has some variation in the x and y position.

`-(void)btnSaveClicked`{

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgView.image.size, NO, 0.0); // create context as the image size
UIImage *dragImage = [self imageWithView:dragView]; // convert image from the dragView
[imgView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imgView.image.size.width, imgView.image.size.height)];  // draw main image

CGSize size = imageDraw.size;
float factor = imgView.image.size.width / imgView.frame.size.width;
if (factor <  imgView.image.size.height / imgView.frame.size.height) {
    factor = imgView.image.size.height / imgView.frame.size.height;
}

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-size.width/factor/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2-size.height/factor/2, size.width/factor, size.height/factor);

CGPoint point = CGPointMake((dragView.frame.origin.x+10-rect.origin.x)*factor,(dragView.frame.origin.y+10 - rect.origin.y)*factor);
[dragImage drawAtPoint:point blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];  // draw the dragImnage but the point is wrong
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
imgView.image = newImage;
```

}

Sample Project : `https://github.com/SunnyShah407/WaterMark/tree/master`

Comment: So you want to apply your rotation and create a new, rotated version of the image? You said "...I have moved the dragView with CGAffineTransformMakeRotation" It would be helpful if you posted the code that creates the rotation transform, and showed what you do with it.

Comment: No at the end i want the draggble view to merge with imageview image. means final image will be the combination of both dragview and Image

Comment: @DuncanC I have added the project on the guthub. if you have a time then please look at this